# ругулярка работает в хроме но не работает в сафари

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, safari

помогите пожалуйста понять что требует сафари? у меня совсем нет времени погружаться в регулярки, надо срочно переписать это в функцию

/^[^+\d]+|(?<=[^+])\D+/g

/^89(?=\d{8})|^79(?=\d{8})/g

Comment: На [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com) вопросы принято задавать только на русском языке. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь [Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: Уже работает, 2024 год на дворе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел похожий вопрос на англоязычной версии сайта.

Попробуйте посмотреть [там](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568821/works-in-chrome-but-breaks-in-safari-invalid-regular-expression-invalid-group).
В посте говорят, что Safari пока что не поддерживает часть вашего регулярного выражения, когда смотрит на [символы назад](https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind).
Как я понял вот эта часть:

> `?<=[^+]`

И так же вот эта:

> `?=`

Насколько я понял, предлагают заменить `/^[^+\d]+|(?<=[^+])\D+/g` на `/^[^+\d]+|(?:[^+])\D+/g`

Впрочем, до конца я не уверен.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Спасибо друг, я решил это почитав таблицу кроссбраузерности с регулярками, понял что именно не работает и изменил это! я сделал ровно как и ты написал, спасибо что не прошел мимо, будь здоров